# how to user_defined in logstash with the kv_plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

in logstash config :

```
 ruby {
            init => "@kname = ['url_path','url_args']"
            code => "
                new_event = LogStash::Event.new(Hash[@kname.zip(event.get('uri').split('?'))])
                new_event.remove('@timestamp')
                event.append(new_event)
            "
        }
        kv {
            prefix => "urlget_"
            source => "url_args"
            field_split => "& "
            remove_field => [ "url_args","uri","request" ]
        }
```

and get the `uri` like

```
"/a/b/c/?prarms=x&parmas=y..."
```

so how to analyze the `uri` to

```
module=a
controller=b
action=c
```

i have try like this:

```
 mutate {
                replace =>{"btc_module"=>"a"}
                replace =>{"btc_action"=>"b"}
                replace =>{"btc_method"=>"c"}
        }
```

how to get the real value a b c in logstash?

or there have some ways to deal in nginx log config?

thanks,
my english should be imporved...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this without dropping into ruby.

First, use the grok{} filter to get the path portion of your URL.  This pattern will work:

> %{URIPATH:myPath}

Then you can grok{} the `myPath` field into your fields with this pattern:

> /%{WORD:btc_module}/%{WORD:btc_action}/%{WORD:btc_method}/

If you don't need the `myPath` field when you're done, put it in "[[metadata]](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-metadata)".